# How to enable Mainframe data on mobile devices using IBM MobileFirst platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Please provide me information on How to enable Mainframe data on mobile devices using IBM MobileFirst platform

Comment: Do you mean how to retrieve data from a mainframe server using adapters in mobilefirst platform?

Answer (score 0):

It is really not clear what does "How to enable Mainframe data on mobile devices using IBM MobileFirst platform" mean... it *sounds* like you want to retrieve data from a backend. To do this you need to use adapters.

You can read more about adapters in the following developer center tutorials:

- Adapters overview: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/adapter-framework-overview/
- HTTP adapter: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/javascript-adapters/js-http-adapter/
- SQL adapter: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/server-side-development-category/javascript-adapters/js-sql-adapter/

There are also plenty of questions detailing how to retrieve information from a backend...

Comment: Thanks for providing me the information Idan, Can these adapters be used to retrieve data from DB2 as well , Please inform on how to retrieve the data from CICS transactions running on Mainframes. Thanks in Advance

Comment: An SQL adapter can connect to DB2, yes. Why do you think everyone would know what is "CICS transactions running on Mainframes"? Please google for more information.